# Would another node client be valuable to Monero environment?

Tags: development

Ethereum seems to have good experience with alternate node clients, would having another one for monero be a good idea or is it still just to early and would maybe slow devs detracting from more progress. thanks all :DD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The propensity for Eth's multiple implementations to fork unexpectedly is a double edged sword. That said I think once Monero is largely feature complete (probably after multisig is rolled out) there's great value in embracing alternative implementations.

So, I guess to answer your question, yes, there are benefits, but it's better for various reasons to focus on making one client as complete and robust as possible before working on new implementations.